# setInterval only running once

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var autoPlaySpeed = 2000;

setInterval(function() { $next.click(); }, autoPlaySpeed);
```

It is only running one time. I have seen many similar questions, but it seems like I have the syntax right. No errors or anything.

Comment: It works fine for me when I change it to  `console.log('');`

Answer (score 1):

I can assure you, the interval will get called every 2 seconds. It is very likely that whatever you think is going to happen in `$next.click();` won't do its job correctly instead.

Try switching that line into `setInterval(function() { alert('annoy me please'); }, autoPlaySpeed);`

Comment: You're right. However, this is the `$next`: `$next = $("#top-slider .slide-right");` - I just want to trigger its click() every two seconds.

Comment: @AE_MM Your code is fine, and I can't help you if you don't post the rest of your code.

Comment: You need to intercept the click event handler then. Try calling it manually, log it and/or debug through the code.